# Pandas pivot table error

Tags: python, pandas

Following code gives

Code:

```
table_channel = pd.pivot_table(data=df,values = 'Category',index = 
['ID'], aggfunc='count')
```

Output:

```
ID    Category
1     2
2     11
3     5
4     3
```

Right now it's giving total count of different categories of Category column.
Need output like:

```
ID    Category1    Category2  Category3
1         0            1          1
2         5            4          2 and so on
```

I used this code to rectify but it did not work:

```
table_channel = pd.pivot_table(df,values = 'Category',columns = 'Category',index = ['ID'], aggfunc='count')
```

Error is that grouper for Category not 1 dimensional.
What is wrong?

Comment: It would be great if you could share an example of your data. This error occurs when you have two columns with same name.

Comment: Try passing Categories as a `columns` parameter as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to use this code instead:

```
columns = df.Category.values
```

Answer (score 3):

You can using `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.ID,df.Category).add_prefix('Category')
Out[1335]: 
Category  Category2  Category3  Category5  Category11
ID                                                   
1                 1          0          0           0
2                 0          0          0           1
3                 0          0          1           0
4                 0          1          0           0
```